# In an Express.js app, how to get the source POST data (the original string)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, express

I'm handling a POST request like so:

```
app.post('/somepage', function (req, res) {

    var post_data = req.body;

});
```

Here, `req.body` already is a JavaScript object (I've tried `console.log(req.body)` and got `[object Object]` in the server's console). I would like to get the original POST data string that was sent with the HTTP request. Is that possible?

Note: I use this middle-ware:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Comment: http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-read-POST-data

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution that might work:

```js
// ...

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var buffer = '';
  req.on('data', function(data) {
    buffer += data.toString();
  }).on('end', function() {
    req.bodyraw = buffer;
  });
  next();
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// ...

app.post('/somepage', function (req, res) {
  var rawpost = req.bodyraw;
});
```

It should be safe since the json and urlencoded middleware add (data) event handlers immediately, but it would be better if the first middleware did `pause()` AND if the json and urlencoded middleware did `resume()` when seeing an explicitly paused stream -- this would guarantee no data could be lost.

Comment: It would be wise to limit the size of the request body.  Otherwise, someone could fill your server's RAM with junk and bring down the app.

Comment: @josh3736 I'm hoping this is just for temporary/debugging purposes and not actually for production, but yes you are right. There ought to be some kind of request size limiter function higher up in the middleware stack.

Comment: shouldn't it be mentioned that this does not apply when using newest version of express? Cause I can't get these examples about collection rawdata to work.. Perhaps I might be doing something wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the 'body-parser' middleware. You have several options to get the body, including as the [raw buffer](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions) or [as text](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions).

Answer (score -2):

app.post('/somepage', function (req, res) {

```
var post_data = req.body.toString();
```

});

Comment: Please don't guess. 1. It doesn't work. (The output is `"[object Object]"`) 2. I need the **original source data** (before ToObject() conversion). I obviously can convert the object to a string if I want to.